# CS0246 error while creating incremental build

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, incremental-build

I have made a small C# application, with 1 solution and 2 projects (`test1`,`test2`). The first project have two files `Program.cs` and `function1.cs`, while second project consist of only `Program2.cs`.
Project `test1` creates `.exe` file, and `test2` creates `.dll` file.
The problem is when I try to build it as VS creates .csproj it runs fine, but when I tried to edit that .csproj (or write my own) to implement incremental build (as it was in example on MS sites) it throws an CS0246

> The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Despite that I have added the references first to `test2.csproj`, and then to `.dll` that it creates, and also using the `using` directive.

The same error occurs when I try to run in command prompt 
`csc.exe program.cs function1.cs`  but it  can be quickly fixed by adding the `/:r` with the `.dll` as in example:

`\csc.exe program.cs function1.cs /r:test2.dll`
And then it runs fine. I just simply dont know how to acknowledge msbuild of that reference between files. And I'm also forced to used cmd instead of building it inside VS.

Below I put code that I use in my project.

Here's the snippet that I'm adding at the end of `test1.csproj` to force it into incremental build:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="function1.cs" />
<Compile Include="Program.cs" />
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="program2">
   <MSBuild Projects="..\test2\test2.csproj" />
   <Message Text="Target program 2" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Compile" Inputs="@(Compile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)   $(AssemblyName).exe" DependsOnTargets="program2">
   <Message Text="Target program 1" />
   <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$OutputPath)')" />
   <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe" />
</Target>
```

Here's the code for `Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace test1
{
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        string pause;
        function1 var = new function1();
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        b = var.funkcja1(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        pause = Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Here's `function1.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using test2;
namespace test1
{
class function1
 {
    public int funkcja1(int a)
    {
        int b;
        Program2 p2 = new Program2();
        b = p2.program2(a);
        return (b);
    }
 }
}
```

And here's code for `Program2.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test2
{
public class Program2
 {
    public class function2
    {
        public int funkcja2(int a)
        {
            return (a + 1);
        }
    }
    public int program2(int c)
    {
        int d;
        function2 var = new function2();
        d = var.funkcja2(c) + 1;
        return (d);
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string pause;
        pause = Console.ReadLine();

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CS0246 error while creating incremental build

You should specify the reference when you build it with `csc.exe`, like `References="..\test2\bin\Debug\test2.dll"`, otherwise, csc.exe could not know the test.dll is referenced by the test1.project, so the target `Compile` looks like:

```
<Target Name="Compile" Inputs="@(Compile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)   $(AssemblyName).exe" DependsOnTargets="program2">
   <Message Text="Target program 1" />
   <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$OutputPath)')" />
   <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe" References="..\test2\bin\Debug\test2.dll" />
</Target>
```

Besides, AFAIK, you should **not** edit that .csproj (or write my own) to implement incremental build directly. That because when you build the project test1, Visual Studio/MSBuild has already used incremental build by default, we do not need to incremental build it again. If you are want to implement incremental build, you can [create a mini MSBuild Project File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx) to implement incremental build. I have created a new `Test.proj` under the test1 project folder with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Compile" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="function1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>MSBuildTestSample</AssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="program2">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\test2\test2.csproj" />
    <Message Text="Target program 2" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Compile" Inputs="@(Compile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath) $(AssemblyName).exe" DependsOnTargets="program2">
    <Message Text="Target program 1" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$OutputPath)')" />
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe" References="..\test2\bin\Debug\test2.dll" />
  </Target>


</Project>
```

Then we could build this `Test.proj` file with MSBuild command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, adding reference fixed the error, and I will use that other file.